# gdaltransform Cartesian transform change 2.2.0 to 3.4.1 proj.4 to?

Tags: gdal, proj, well-known-text

Here are my results with 2.2.0 and 3.4.1. Can someone explain why this has changed?

```
echo -e "6720419.518191041 1878355.8391366536 1387.976960406033" | \
  gdaltransform \
    -s_srs "+proj=lcc +lat_0=33.5 +lon_0=-118 +lat_1=35.4666666666667 +lat_2=34.0333333333333 +x_0=2000000.0001016 +y_0=500000.0001016 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs" \
    -t_srs "+proj=geocent +ellps=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

2.2.0 docker

-4228902.87475802 -3787430.60541586 2897550.34854807

3.4.1 ubuntu

2295951.71065758 -4752631.348586 3571205.19419829
```

Update:
Ok, based on some discussion on Github, it looks like the problem has to do with the 2.2 image using proj.4 instead of whatever proj is used by 3.4.1

If it helps, here is the original WKT

```
PROJCS["NAD83(2011) / California zone 5 (ftUS)",GEOGCS["NAD83(2011)",DATUM["NAD83_National_Spatial_Reference_System_2011",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","1116"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6318"]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",35.46666666666667],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",34.03333333333333],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",33.5],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-118],PARAMETER["false_easting",6561666.667],PARAMETER["false_northing",1640416.667],UNIT["US survey foot",0.3048006096012192,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9003"]],AXIS["X",EAST],AXIS["Y",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6424"]]
```

Comment: I'm maintaining legacy code that calls this, so assume I know nothing lol

Comment: @user2856 `PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"]` again, I don't know much about this topic, how do you get UTM?

Comment: And this WKT is parsed and converted to the s_srs

Comment: the WKT is the camera view output of a Pix4D project. I think we are translating each camera position from what's in the WKT to geocentric

Comment: Ignore, I didn't read the WKT carefully enough.